# Horizontally align divs

Tags: html, inline

Trying to align three floating divs horizontally and for some reason I get a rise from the second and third div. Trying to have all of these three inline.

Any ideas

```
<style type="text/css">
#main {
vertical-align: middle;
alignment-adjust: middle;
}
.floater {
    float:left;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="main">
<div class="floater"><select name="test"></select> 
</div>
<div class="floater"><select name="test"></select>
</div>
<div class="floater"><select name="test"></select>
</div>

 </div>
```

Comment: It seems to work well ? [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Remc/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be working, but here is an alternative way of doing it :

```
 <style type="text/css">
    .floater {
        display:inline;
    }
    </style>

    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="main">
    <div class="floater"><select name="test"></select> 
    </div>
    <div class="floater"><select name="test"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="floater"><select name="test"></select>
    </div>

     </div>
```

EXAMPLE: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4BRVm/)

Comment: It may have something to do with some additional css. I ran it through dreamweaver and it works fine with my initial code. But ran against worklight and it shifts up the additional divs like stair steps. I may need to override it with !important;

Comment: it could be a worklight configuration problem, try with other editors to make sure its not of your css styles.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your main div, add a table with single row and 3 cells. Place the individual divs inside each cell.